# php session и object

Tags: php, сессия

Использую в начале страницы:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['db'])) $_SESSION['db'] = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'mydb');
$db = $_SESSION['db'];
```

Далее на странице работа с запросами идет нормально.
Запускаю некий скрипт через ajax, в котором в начале страницы:

```
session_start();
$db = (object) $_SESSION['db'];
```

И тут работа с запросами не идет, ошибки при запросах, как будто нет отключения, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Вы что-то делаете совсем не так. В каждом новом процессе (а это у вас новый процесс) вы должны инициализировать соединение с базой данных, если вы к ней хотите получить доступ. И старый указатель на соединение вам не поможет.

Comment: Возможно лучше записывать в переменную значения для соединения (хост, логин, пароль, бд), а потом создавать новое соединение в коде ?

Comment: Visman, вы правы, теперь я понял

Comment: Ep1demic, да, такой вариант подойдет.